# How to rename multiple columns names with format date?

Tags: r, function, date

I'd like to create a rename_col_df() function that renames all the columns in a data.frame except the first one (CODE_S).

Here's an example to reproduce the problem:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  CODE_S = c(1, 2, 3),
  COL2 = c(10, 20, 30),
  COL3 = c(15, 25, 35)
)
colnames(df) <- c("CODE_S", "01/10/2023", "01/11/2023")
```

In this example, I only have 2 date columns, but in the real use case I have dozens of them.

Expected result: columns named "CODE_S", "2023-10-01", "2023-11-01".

I was thinking of using something like this but I can't get it into a function:

```r
names(df) <- c("CODE_S",format(as.Date("01/11/2023", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: Maybe just replace / to - : `gsub("/", "-", c("CODE_S", "01/10/2023", "01/11/2023"), fixed = TRUE)`, or use `make.names` to get valid names.

Comment: I'd like it to work without having to write for example "01/11/2023" in the code

Comment: And you can use `colnames(df)[-1] <- gsub("/", "-", colnames(df)[-1L])`, if only the first column name is different.

Comment: It was just an example, there is no need to type column names manually, use colnames, then gsub, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using your idea and `rename_with`:

```
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  rename_with(~format(as.Date(., format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d"), -"CODE_S")
```

**Output**

```
  CODE_S 2023-10-01 2023-11-01
1      1         10         15
2      2         20         25
3      3         30         35
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
> colnames(df)[-1]=as.character(as.Date(colnames(df)[-1],format="%d/%m/%Y"))
  CODE_S 2023-10-01 2023-11-01
1      1         10         15
2      2         20         25
3      3         30         35
```

Column names cannot be dates.

Answer (score 1):

Using *gsub*:

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("/", "-", colnames(df), fixed = TRUE)
```

Or *make.names* to have valid names:

```
colnames(df) <- make.names(colnames(df))
```